# Outlook mobile plugin for IMAP users

Tags: mobile, plug-in, outlook, imap

I want to create an Outlook add-in for both desktop and mobile but according to the overview in https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/add-in-requirements Outlook add-ins is not supported for IMAP connected clients. So I've found VSTO to build an add-in for Outlook desktop clients. However, it is not possible to create one for mobile with VSTO. Hence, I need a way to build an add-in for Outlook mobile, so that IMAP connected users can use it.

Comment: i'm still not sure what you are asking for: a caldav plugin for outlook mobile? - a caldav plugin for outlook? - a general caldav client for desktop/mobile? - or a caldav server (perhaps with a webGUI)?

Comment: I'm not asking for a caldav plugin. I'm asking to build a plugin in that can be used by user connected Outlook clients via IMAP.

Comment: IMAP is e-mail only, so you still need a caldav (or exchange) sever for the calendar. **||** can you please rephrase your "question" to make it clear what you are asking.

Comment: Yes, I know the difference. But what I'm trying to say is we don't have a caldav server and not gonna build one, because we tried so many open source calendar projects like Horde, SoGo, Nextcloud etc., yet they didn't give what we're looking for exactly.

Comment: So, for starter, I'm trying to build a very simple application that would do the creating events and sharing the meetings for Outlook clients. It's okay with the desktop, but I need it in mobile too. I'm actually asking for help to build a mobile Outlook plug-in. I can't use Outlook Add-ins cause the official document says IMAP clients cant use that.

Comment: 1) i still don't really get it... so where are you going to store the calendars? on the exchange server? - so why you then don't use the exchange server as it is supposed to be used with the MAPI/EWS protocol?!? ...then all your problems are gone.

Comment: 2) if you sooner or later want to switch to CalDAV: it sounds to me, that you just need a CalDAV backend (without WebGUI)... then i would rather try [Radicale](https://radicale.org/), [DAViCal](https://www.davical.org/) or [Baïkal](http://sabre.io/baikal/) depending on the amount of users and your skills... or perhaps have a look at https://devguide.calconnect.org/CalDAV/Server-Implementations/

Comment: 3) once again: can you please [**edit** your post](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/posts/65740/edit) and rephrase it (e.g. don't mention CalDAV if your question has nothing to do with CalDAV) and actually **formulate a real question**. - please keep in mind, this is about questions and software recommendations and not about announcements.

Comment: 4) *"[...] build a very simple application that would do the creating events and sharing the meetings [...]"* - btw handling (recurring) events and syncing them is not as trivial as you probably think! - hopefully you know what you are doing.

Comment: *"[...] we tried so many open source calendar projects like Horde, SoGo, Nextcloud etc., yet they didn't give **what we're looking for exactly**."* - 
a completely new approach: maybe create an other question and **clearly** describe your needs, workflow and what a solution should and must not do... perhaps the community can help at that point and save you tons of hours of fiddling around with a quirky solution.

Comment: Okay, I'm editing the post.

Comment: thank you for clarifying your "question"! **||** sorry for [repeating myself](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/65740/outlook-mobile-plugin-for-imap-users#comment85315_65740): why you don't use the exchange server with the MAPI/EWS protocol to also access/sync calendars?!?